# return mysql result set only if found in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not so good at JOIN statements in MySQL queries so I hoped someone could help me out with this one:

Two tables - `videos` & `video_groups`. Entries in `videos` feature the field `groupid` which is a reference to the `id` in `video_groups`. What I need to do is return only results from `video_groups` that have at least one video...

Something like
`SELECT * FROM video_groups WHERE video_groups.id...` and no idea how to continue...

I have tried to search for something, but as I don't really know what to look for I am lost :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT vg.*
    FROM video_groups vg
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM videos v
                      WHERE v.groupid = vg.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

A regular JOIN will only join rows where it finds rows in both tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vg.id
FROM video_groups vg
JOIN videos v
ON vg.id = v.groupid
ORDER BY vg.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM video_groups WHERE id = '...'
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort Sam, however, you did not get the point of the question...